# Unable connect Remote server thru SSH in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Scenario: While connecting Server asking mountpoint details dynamic, so getting below error

**Script**

```
node('agent') {

stage('Sync Repo') {  
  sshagent(['poc_ssh_key']) {
sh """
ssh -p XXX user@IP $mountpoint(Data003)

""" 
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
error:
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!! This system has been onboarded to TPAM.   Please use the TPAM interface link below to request privileged access to the server.
!!  TPAM URL:   
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Please enter the root path variable [data001/data002/data003/data004/data005]
You entered:
```

Answer (score 0):

After lot of invesgation , found below solution and it's working as expected.

node('agent') {

stage('Sync Repo') {
  sshagent(['poc_ssh_key']) {

```
 sh """
 echo 'data003' | ssh -p 2022 user@IP

 """
```

}
}